# Не учитывается локаль для gets и scanf при считывании строки

Tags: c, строки, char, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <locale.h>
int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");
    char string[10];
    int var,i;
    scanf("%s", string);
    for (i=0;i<10;i++){
        printf(" %c ", string[i]);
    }    
    return 0;
}
```

При вводе 'приветhey' в ответ получаю ' Ї  а  Ё  ў  ?  в  h  e  y '. Почему русские буквы не читаются? Тоже самое с gets

Comment: Зачем вы даете неправильный заголовок? Ведь и gets и scanf у вас на самом деле работают.

Answer (score 1):

Уже нашел решение. Надо поменять способ установления локали. Вместо `#include <locale.h>` `setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");` Необходимо поставить `#include <windows.h>` `SetConsoleCP (1251); SetConsoleOutputCP (1251);` ну и, конечно, шрифт консоли поменять, если уже не стоит нужный.